# vim remove non existing mapping

Tags: vim, mapping

Background scenario: When I was debugging one VimScript, some code is not executed. The reason is that unmap raises one error and the VimScript exits on this error. Because one empty try-catch is place around the code, it's not very obvious what's the problem. After locating the problem finally, I begin to think maybe this default behavior is not very intuitive.

This is some simple code to illustrate that vim reports error on removing non existing mapping, experimentally. It will fail on the last line, saying sth like "E31: No such mapping".

```
map <F10> :echo 'hello'
unmap <F10>
unmap <F10>
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any doc on this behavior. Could someone point me where I could some explanation on removing non existing mapping? What's the rational behind this design? Personally, I would regard removing non existing mappings as one normal statement, and continue as usual.

EDIT: There might be some misunderstanding to this question. I am not asking how to suppress the error. I would like to know why vim thinks removing one non existing mapping is one error. Is it so serious?

As pointed out in the answers and comments, it's unix philosophy to raise one error when it could do the operation asked. I fully agree with it, but in shell, script continue on error by default, so the same reasoning shouldn't be applied.

PS:As recommended, this question has been moved to [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/xSZ4PrkltVk).

Comment: look at `:help E31` for the doc reference

Comment: @FDinoff It only documents when this error is raised, not why vim throws this error.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) That is why I think this question isn't really suited for Stackoverflow.

Comment: One possible reason is most unix tools give errors if it can't do what you asked. For example if you do `rm somefile_that_doesnt_exist` you will get an error because it was unable to preform the command. (ie no such file or directory). Same sort of logic would apply for unmap

Comment: @FDinoff The default behavior of shell is that it continues on error, so error in shell is not as serious as it is in VimScript. In VimScript, current script will abort on error.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk From my simple tests I do not see vim aborting on error. I do not believe vim aborts on error. What makes you think this?

Comment: @FDinoff What I meant is that the current script doesn't continue any more, not vim itself. (Vim would be too fragile to abort on such a simple error.)

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Thats what I meant too. I put echos after the unmap and the echos printed.

Comment: @FDinoff Put it into the `:try` block. The reason why you must always avoid errors not inside `:try` block (or `:silent!`, but I prefer not to do this) is that whenever you have an error outside of it you can no longer tell whether or not execution will continue after the error. For errors inside you can always tell that it will abort. It is possible for user to put absolutely any code into `:try` conditional. After recent changes any code run from `python` (e.g. via `vim.command` or `vim.eval`) also aborts at the error (vim errors or exceptions are propagated as a python exceptions).

Comment: @FDinoff My original understanding was wrong. Statements after error are skipped, if there's one try-catch around this statement, as pointed out by Zyx.

Comment: @ZyX I discovered this 'try-catch' behavior just now. VimScript will continue on error, if it's not inside one try-catch block, but it will skip the following statements if there's one. It's one quite surprising behavior, that the caller could change the callee's execution flow externally by wrapping the function inside one try-catch block.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk This is why I suggest to force `:try` if there is a possibility for the error and use `:echohl ErrorMsg|:echom` or `:throw` in place of `:echoerr`. One can execute code inside `:try`, but one cannot execute code already wrapped in `:try` without it.

Answer (score 5):

It fails because `do_map` returns 2 for unknown mapping and [this code](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/5bb04d03dfa843c1080ed3872daacc42caa86542/src/ex_docmd.c#cl-8406) throws error for this case. Not very helpful, I guess. Annotate says that this code did not change from the very first version of vim found in the mercurial repository (7.0001).

There may be different answers: I can guess of three:

1. vi compatibility: `vi` did throw and so should vim do
2. it is right thing to do: if command did not do what it was requested to do it should report failure
3. it provides more options: if unmapping an *existing* mapping is essential you can catch the error using `:try`..`:catch` (or leave as-is indicating the error to user), if it is not there is always `silent!`. Argument for [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle adepts and users with tiny vim though: in VimL using `maparg()` to check for existence is more common, but it requires `+eval` (if I am not mistaking `:try` does this as well: the whole meaningful `ex_eval.c` file contents where this command is defined is guarded with `#if defined(FEAT_EVAL) || defined(PROTO)`).

But Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask such questions. For such old code only Bram may know the answer and thus the question should be asked on [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/vim_dev). If I were him I would ask an explanation why you need the answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The [link](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/5bb04d03dfa843c1080ed3872daacc42caa86542/src/ex_docmd.c#cl-8406) is broken. Re:1. I get this behavior with `nocompatible`. Re:2. it has already achieve the requested final result, the mapping doesn't exist now. Re:3. There's always `silent!` for sure, but what I am questioning is the default behavior. It's not very intuitive. PS: the explanation of why I ask this question is added to this question. As recommended, it's moved to vim-dev. Thanks.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Link is fixed (pushed relevant changesets, did not actually change the link).

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Re1: If you think all vi compatibility ends at setting `nocompatible` you are absolutely wrong. Re2: You asked to do some job: *unmap*, you did not ask about final result. Job was not done. Re3: There is `:silent` to *suppress* error. There is no `:unsilent` to make it throw (existing `:unsilent` only cancels the effect of `silent`).

Comment: Re1: I mean, since we have `nocompatible`, being compatible with vi shouldn't be one convincing argument. Re2: Fair enough, but the whether the job (removing some mapping) is finished or not is not important. Re3: What error could appear on removing non-existing mapping?

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Re1: If that is how vi worked to remove this behavior you need to be more convincing than you are. Any option that takes out compatibility introduces complexity and *this* is an argument. Vim already has too much options. Re3: This may indicate that you are operating in the wrong environment: e.g. you have created buffer-local mapping, switched buffers and after not handling this switch properly tried to undo these mappings. Such message may help in debugging why local mappings disturb user after they should have already be junked.

Comment: Re1: Note that [AFAIK](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/src/87d6016bd40061800c44451d3451ca52ebfdd026/src/option.c#cl-11492) 'compatible' option does nothing else then resetting other options. At least this is how I read this code. Thus altering the behavior of `:unmap` in `nocompatible` mode will create yet another option plugin developers must be aware of to make their code more portable.

Comment: I agree with you that there's not much difference between `cp` and `nocp`, according to the code. (Quite surprising, for some critics on vim is that it differs too much from vi.) How much impact introducing this inconsistency will put on plugin developers might not be as much as you concerned, for most of the plugins I use, such as [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/plugin/fugitive.vim), [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/plugin/ctrlp.vim) begin with `if &cp finish endif`.

Comment: Personally, I think, sometimes, it's good that the community moves on without being hindered by outdated options.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Authors of new plugins tend not to bother about options different from what they have on their setup until problem does not hit them. `if &cp` condition is an example of this: it does nothing to prevent problems with problematic `&cpo` setting which actually may introduce problems. All or most plugins distributed with vim use `let s:save_cpo=&cpo|set cpo&vim|…|let &cpo=s:save_cpo` or like and it makes more sense because I can break fugitive with `cpo&vi` without setting `&cp` to true.

Comment: Thus I am against any option which should possibly be cared of, I already know that I do not handle properly a bunch of possible option combinations. If your proposal does not introduce problems for existing code it does not mean it will not introduce problems for the future code. In fact, if the default changed according to your proposal your code will become buggy, but you have not noticed it. I have [a list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/vim_dev/defaults/vim_dev/De5RiYIDB5U/V7tRHiY59zEJ) of options possibly introducing problems and it is very large.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress any error by prepending `:silent!`, i.e.

```
:silent! unmap <F10>
```

There are other ways (e.g. a conditional checking whether `maparg('<F10>', 'n')` is empty), but this is the canonical way to execute a command and ignore any errors.

Comment: Nice trick. My idea for surpressing the error is to wrap it inside one try-catch. Yours is much more elegant. However, this is not what I want to ask originally. See Edited question for clarification of the question.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk One `try..catch` is a better way unless you are absolutely sure “no such mapping” is the only error vim may show you. Note: one `try..catch /\C\V\^Vim(unmap):E31:/`, not catch without a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can edit the file in which the mapping is stored and manually remove it if necessary.  Here's a link with some more info:

[Removing a keymap](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Removing_a_keymap)